# Getting a Makefile to work on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile

I submitted some code for an interview assignment that included a Makefile for the employers to use to compile everything. However, they're using VS 2015. When executing using NMAKE, they get the following error: "makefile(9) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '+' in macro Stop."

This is the Makefile:

```
CC=g++
C++FLAGS=-g -Wall
INCLUDES=-I.
ALL_OBJ = main.o pond.o duck.o 
PROG_NAME= goldenPond

%.o : %.cpp
    g++  -c $< -o $@ $(C++FLAGS)

$(PROG_NAME): $(ALL_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(C++FLAG) -o $@ $(ALL_OBJ) $(INCLUDES)

all:
    make $(PROG_NAME)

clean:
    (rm -f *.o;)
```

From my understanding, my Makefile doesn't work on VS because it uses a different compiler (I'm using mingw). Would I be able to just change a few things in this Makefile to have it work on visual studio or would the process be entirely different?

Comment: Consider using [SCONS](http://scons.org) or [CMake](https://cmake.org) - those (meta) build systems largely try to abstract such things as platforms and compilers away..

Comment: I would avoid using + in your variable names.

Comment: @JesperJuhl would I be able to use CMake to create a build for VS 2015 without having VS myself?

Comment: @trungnt sure, you just wouldn't be able to test it ;)

Comment: CMake is an abstraction of the build system. It can create on demand a VS project or a makefile or a nmake file etc....

Comment: @JesperJuhl so I used cmake to make project for VS 2015. It worked fine on my computer. However, when I tried using it on another computer, I get the following errors https://imgur.com/a/172m4. It seems to still use my old computer's directory